# How to loop to create folders?

Tags: python, recursion, directory

I want to create multiple folders from 0 to 9.
In each folder there are again folders from 0 to 9 and so on.

On repeat for the 5th directory or the 10th directory or whatever I want.

#### Code

```
import os
for a in range(10):
    os.makedirs("D:/Test/"+str(a))
    for b in range(10):
        os.makedirs("D:/Test/"+str(a)+"/"+str(b))
        for c in range(10):
            os.makedirs("D:/Test/"+str(a)+"/"+str(b)+"/"+str(c))
            for d in range(10):
                os.makedirs("D:/Test/"+str(a)+"/"+str(b)+"/"+str(c)+"/"+str(d))
                for e in range(10):
                    os.makedirs("D:/Test/"+str(a)+"/"+str(b)+"/"+str(c)+"/"+str(d)+"/"+str(e))
                    for f in range(10):
                        os.makedirs("D:/Test/"+str(a)+"/"+str(b)+"/"+str(c)+"/"+str(d)+"/"+str(e)+"/"+str(f))
                        for g in range(10):
                            os.makedirs("D:/Test/"+str(a)+"/"+str(b)+"/"+str(c)+"/"+str(d)+"/"+str(e)+"/"+str(f)+"/"+str(g))
                            for h in range(10):
                                os.makedirs("D:/Test/"+str(a)+"/"+str(b)+"/"+str(c)+"/"+str(d)+"/"+str(e)+"/"+str(f)+"/"+str(g)+"/"+str(h))
                                for i in range(10):
                                    os.makedirs("D:/Test/"+str(a)+"/"+str(b)+"/"+str(c)+"/"+str(d)+"/"+str(e)+"/"+str(f)+"/"+str(g)+"/"+str(h)+"/"+str(i))
```

The code I made is long and manual. Instead I want to have a loop for each directory I want to add.

Comment: this is going to create `1,000,000,000` directories. If it takes a millisecond to create a directory, it will take more than 11 days to finish. But you'll fill up your disk long before then.

Comment: You can just use `range(1000000000)` and then split that up into digits. You only need to make the last directory in the sequence, `os.makedirs()` will automatically make the intermediate directories.

Comment: yeah, but what is the point of creating that many folders?

Comment: @DaniyalWarraich i just started learning python so i'm doing it as practice and I got inspiration from a meme I saw

Comment: Watch out for the `rm -r *` meme.

Comment: Still not a good idea, because as @Barmar stated, it will create 1, 000, 000, 000 folders.

Comment: Please note that `os.makedirs` will create any necessary intermediate folders, so you only need the innermost call - that's the *point* of it (otherwise you could use `os.mkdir`).

Comment: @Barmar good that i don't use linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, this will take forever and fill up your disk. But here's a simpler way to do it:

```
for i in range(1000000000):
    dir = os.path.join('C:/Test', *f"{i:09d}")
    os.makedirs(dir)
```

`f"{i:09d}"` will convert the number to a string with leading zeroes, and `*` before that will spread each digit into a separate argument to `os.path.join()`.

You don't need to call `os.makedirs()` at each level of nesting, because it automatically creates intermediate directories when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In programming, when the same code needs to be run repeatedly, it should be in a method/function:

```
def my_fn(path):
  for a in range(10):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(path,str(a)))
```

Nesting like this is called `recursion`. Basically your function will need to call itself as a last step, but it's important to know *when* to stop; the solution is to have a stop-variable:

```
def my_fn(path, depth=0):
  if depth >= 5:
    # stop creating folders after 5 folders deep
    return

  <create folders>

  for fol in list_of_new_folders:
    my_fn(os.path.join(path,fol), depth+1)
```

Comment: the issue is that you can't go too deep and also it seems you have a syntax error in your code or at least you misplaced the paranthese

Comment: (parenthesis fixed ) you can [try] to go as deep as you want - whether or not that is a good idea is a valid question, which has been pointed out in the comments on the main question.